# Как составить маску для $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо определить при помощи $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] заканчивается ли url текущей страницы на `.html`

Как составить маску, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: возьми через substr последние 5 символов да сравни с `.html` ....... или разбей через `explode` с разделителем точки и возьми последний элемент полученного массива и сравни с `html`

Comment: Боюсь вам не стоит пилить такое, лучше приведите задачу полностью, что надо то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимум три способа (не считая регулярки) сравнения с нужным значением:

1. Взять последние символы в строке по длине, равной со сравниваемой строкой:

   ```
   $search = 'html';
   $str = '/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php';   
   $lastChars =  substr($str, -strlen($search));
   if ($search != $lastChars) echo 'Это строка не оканчивается на html';
   ```

   **[substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)** - возвращает подстроку строки `string`, начинающейся с указанной позиции и указанной. Если стартовая позиция указана отрицательной, возвращаемая подстрока начинается с конца строки.
2. Разбить через **[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)** разбить по разделителю "точка" и взять последний элемент

   ```
   $search = 'html';
   $str = '/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php';
   $exploded = explode('.', $str);
   $lastChars = array_pop($exploded);
   if ($search != $lastChars) echo 'Это строка не оканчивается на html';
   ```
3. Воспользоваться **[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)** - возвращает информацию о пути к файлу

   ```
   $str = '/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php';
   $path_parts = pathinfo($str);

   echo 'dirname: ' . $path_parts['dirname'], "<br/>";
   echo 'basename: ' . $path_parts['basename'], "<br/>";
   echo 'extension: ' . $path_parts['extension'], "<br/>";
   echo 'filename: ' . $path_parts['filename'], "<br/>"; // начиная с PHP 5.2.0

   if ($search != $path_parts['extension']) echo 'Это строка не оканчивается на html';
   ```
4. Регулярки.
5. Да еще куча разных способов, извращенных и очень извращенных.